# Amigos una consulta, estoy trabajando con bootstrap y llamo un modal, envio un comentario aparece un caracter extraño

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Así envío y llamo a mi modal desde jquery....

```
$('#modalcontenidodos').text("Este DNI ya tiene un usuario y contraseña.");                           
$('#mymodaldos').modal('show');
```

pero me sale un carácter extraño en el modal así.....

> Este DNI ya tiene un usuario y contraseÃ±a.

Comment: Por favor comparte todo el HTML, es un problema de codificación clásico y con solo ver la llamada al modal no podemos hacer nada puesto que el problema no está ahí

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir en tu html en la parte de META la codificación que vas a usar.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: ya lo tengo definido amigo, y me sale igual, lo tenía ya antes definido, que podria ser

Answer (score 0):

En vez de poner ñ, pon el código HTML: `&ntilde;`